# Connect configuration variables just once in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some files:

**tags.js:**

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    monk = require('monk'),
    db = monk('localhost:27017/data');

...

module.exports = router;
```

**records.js:**

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    monk = require('monk'),
    db = monk('localhost:27017/data');

...

module.exports = router;
```

**users.js:**

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    monk = require('monk'),
    db = monk('localhost:27017/data');

...

module.exports = router;
```

All the time I have to **duplicate my header**:

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    monk = require('monk'),
    db = monk('localhost:27017/data');
```

What's the best solution to connect this **configuration variables just once**?

---

I **tried** this variant [In Node.js, how do I "include" functions from my other files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797852/in-node-js-how-do-i-include-functions-from-my-other-files), but that doesn't work, becouse I should use require (for example: require('express')) in tools.js and I got errors.

I also **tried** this variant [node.js - accessing required variables from other files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542122/node-js-accessing-required-variables-from-other-files):

**toolkit.js:**

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    monk = require('monk'),
    db = monk('localhost:27017/data');
```

**tags.js:**

```
var tools = require('../toolkit'),
    router = tools.router;

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
...
});

module.exports = router;
```

but I got errors again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export from `toolkit.js`. So, your `toolkit` will look like

```
var express = require('express');
exports.router = express.Router();
var monk = require('monk');
exports.db = monk('localhost:27017/data');
```

Now, you can do:

```
var toolkit = require('path/to/toolkit');
var router = toolkit.router;
var db = toolkit.db;
```